# Nested literals in JavaScript, a good idea?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I stumbled upon a pattern in JavaScript that I refer to as a `nested literal'. It works because you can have self invoking function literals as arguments of self invoking function literals.

A self invoking function literal is a function that immediately evaluates itself, like so:

```
(function(arg1, arg2) { return arg1 + arg2; }) (1, 2);
```

This is equivalent to writing

```
3;
```

One advantage of using such self invoking function literals is that its code is strictly top-down, which makes it very easy to understand. Consider

```
document.write(
    (function(
        factorial,
        square
    ) {
        return factorial(square(3));
    } (
        function f(x) {
            if (x <= 1) return 1;
            else return x * f(x - 1);
        },
        function f(x) {
            return x*x;
        }
    ))
);
```

Assuming you recognize the argument of document.write() as a self invoking function literal, you don't have to be very smart to understand that this program writes the factorial of the square of three to a page, and to understand how the factorial and square functions are implemented. The program reads intuitively as "in the document, write the factorial of the square of 3, where factorial is ... and square is ... .".

What's more, there is nothing from stopping you of making one of the arguments of a self invoking function literal such a function literal itself. For example:

```
(function(arg1, arg2) { return arg1 + arg2 }) (
    1,
    (function(arg1, arg2) { return arg1 + arg2 })(2, 3)
);
```

This is equivalent to writing

```
6;
```

This nesting can go on and on, allowing you to make extremely complex literals that are very simple to understand. Consider the final program:

```
document.write(
    /* text = */ (
        (function(
            title,
            section1,
            section2,
            section3
        ) {
            return ('<h3>' + title + '</h3>' +
                    section1 +
                    section2 +
                    section3
                   );
        } (
            /* title = */ (
                'Nested Literals in JavaScript'
            ),
            /* section1 = */ (
                (function(
                    title_section1,
                    paragraph1_section1,
                    paragraph2_section1
                ) {
                    return ('<h4>' + title_section1 + '</h4>' +
                            '<p>' + paragraph1_section1 + '</p>' +
                            '<p>' + paragraph2_section1 + '</p>'
                           );
                } (
                    /* title_section1 = */ (
                        'Nested Literals'
                    ),
                    /* paragraph1_section1 = */ (
                        "JavaScript allows nested literals through its self invocating function literals.  This is because self invocating function literals take literals as arguments.  Therefore, a self invocating function literal can take an argument that is a self invocating function literal that can take an argument that is ... ."
                    ),
                    /* paragraph2_section1 = */ (
                        "This is cool! for it allows arbitrarily complex literals.  This program consists out of a single call to document.write(), its argument being relatively complex."
                    )
                ))
            ),
            /* section2 = */ (
                (function(
                    title_section2,
                    paragraph1_section2,
                    paragraph2_section2,
                    paragraph3_section2
                ) {
                    return ('<h4>' + title_section2 + '</h4>' +
                            '<p>' + paragraph1_section2 + '</p>' +
                            '<p>' + paragraph2_section2 + '</p>' +
                            '<p>' + paragraph3_section2 + '</p>'
                           );
                } (
                    /* title_section2 = */ (
                        'Top-Down Coding'
                    ),
                    /* paragraph1_section2 = */ (
                        "Using nested literals, your code can become very readable.  Reading the code from top to bottom you will get to understand the structure top-down, which is how we (at least I) like it."
                    ),
                    /* paragraph2_section2 = */ (
                        "This code is an example of this.  What it does is probably obvious on your first read.  If not, then it is probably because you are not familiar enough with self invocating function literals, yet."
                    ),
                    /* paragraph3_section2 = */ (
                        "And not only does it makes programs easy to read, it makes them easy to write."
                    )
                ))
            ),
            /* section3 = */ (
                (function(
                    title_section3,
                    paragraph1_section3,
                    paragraph2_section3,
                    paragraph3_section3
                ) {
                    return ('<h4>' + title_section3 + '</h4>' +
                            '<p>' + paragraph1_section3 + '</p>' +
                            '<p>' + paragraph2_section3 + '</p>' +
                            '<p>' + paragraph3_section3 + '</p>'
                           );
                } (
                    /* title_section3 = */ (
                        'Local Variables Only'
                    ),
                    /* paragraph1_section3 = */ (
                        "Because everything is literal, or anonymous, no assignments are made.  This keeps the global scope completely clean."
                    ),
                    /* paragraph2_section3 = */ (
                        "Also, arguments to a self invocating function literal are outside the scope of the body of the self invocating function literal.  This makes their scopes completely separated.  Even though their behaviour is nested, their scopes are not." 
                    ),
                    /* paragraph3_section3 = */ (
                        "This puts nested literals in contrast to nested functions, which allow their behaviour to get tangled up with the variables of the function in which they are nested."
                    )
                ))
            )
        ))
    )
);
```

I think it is obvious what it does. You can run it by clicking in text field of your adress bar, typing 'javascript:', pasting the above source code and pressing enter.

What I am unsure about is how efficient the use of nested literals is. I wonder if you would run into any trouble if you would take this to the extreme. I am wondering if anyone knows.

Anyway, I just wanted to share this, perhaps hear what you think.

Regards, Pieter Jan

Comment: Virtually all modern Javascript frameworks do stuff like this all the time.  Also, technically the functions aren't "self-invoking"; it's more accurate to call them "immediately invoked anonymous functions" or something. Check out the Underscore.js and Functional.js libraries for some nice examples of coding in a functional style with Javascript.

Comment: I disagree on "simple to understand". Not that I can't read and understand it, but I want to punch you in the face for writing it.

Comment: Read up on functional programming. Respectfully, the chance that you are going to invent a novel design pattern by stumbling into it with so many other smart people and researchers out there is really low.

Comment: I wasn't expecting to come up with a new pattern. I just hadn't seen this pattern explicitly, which is likely given I haven't read a lot of code. This is why I just presented it the way I understand it.
From your comments I understand that I should look into functional programming with JavaScript to realize this pattern is a common one. I will do that. Thx!

Comment: I agree 'immediately invoked' is more accurate than 'self invoked', but the last one is what I heard most.

Answer (score 3):

All I would say is: Make sure your code is readable. Don't do something like this just because it's cool that you *can* do it. Do it if it makes your code more readable. Which sometimes it does, and sometimes it definitely doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I agree that readability has high priority. Nested literals can be made very readable because reading it from top to bottom lets you read the literal structure top-down. I can imagine that if you're not used to such use of literals, it looks very strange and therefore complicated.

Comment: But if you realize you're simply looking at a tree, I would say the last program is very easy to understand and modify.

Answer (score 1):

I can see at least two major reasons why it's not a good idea

- You code becomes slower - every time you do a function call in javascript, a new callstack has to be initialized amongst other things, it is a massive overhead if what the function does is trivial and only needs to happen once, this of instance is why doing a normal loop is so much faster than using convenience methods like jQuerys .each, that calls a function on every iteration.
- If you need to do the same thing twice or more, do use functions, but give them names and reference them, that way you code will be infinitely easier to maintain, and named functions also gives you the benefit of being profileable - try to profile a lot of javascript littered with anonymous functions is like clapping with one hand.

Comment: When I read it I found it interesting then like > clapping with one hand.

Comment: I see. The profiling argument is a good one.
I agree that using a function in several places should always be a reason to make it visible so that the same code can be reused. There is little sense in having two pieces of code with exactly the same functionality, or even overlapping functionality.